# C# Proxy using Sockets, how should I do this?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, proxy

> I'm writing a proxy using .NET and C#.
>   I haven't done much Socket programming, and I am not sure the best way to go about it. 
>   What would be the best way to implement this? 
>   Should I use Synchronous Sockets, Asynchronous sockets? Please help!

It must...

- Accept Connections from the client on
  two different ports, and be able to
  receive data on both ports at the
  same time.
- Connect to the server on two different ports, and be able to send data on both ports as the same time.
- Immediately connect to the server and start forwarding packets as soon as a client connection is made.
- Forward packets in the same order they were received.
- Be as low latency as possible.
- I don't need the ability for multiple
  clients to connect to the proxy, but it
  would be a nice feature if its easy
  to implement.

> Client --------- Proxy ------- Server
>   ---|-----------------|----------------|
>   Port <--------> Port <-------> Port
>   Port <--------> Port <-------> Port

Comment: Can you limit your code to running on Windows Server 2008?

Comment: No, it has to at least run on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tinkered with [this source code](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/proxy/) before.  It was done well, recommended.

Comment: This is quite easy to follow, thanks! It's not compiling with 3.5 though, and it is quite old. Is there anything specific I should avoid doing (outdated, or better way) that is used in this?

Comment: @kin - compile issues are easily fixed by compiling as .NET 1.1 (not tried) or by casting the expression inside the offending Math.Floor as double.

Comment: Address compiler issue: Use BitConverter.ToInt64(IP.GetAddressBytes(), 0) vs IP.Address.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out [PortFusion](http://portfusion.sourceforge.net)! It is a complete, actively-used and -developed distributed reverse proxy solution for **all** TCP-based traffic. It is written for .NET 4.0 and comes with full source code.

I have tested ReceiveAsync and SendAsync methods introduced in .NET 3.5 but have not found them to reach as high a throughput as is possible with synchronous ones - Async ones should scale better in case of a great number of concurrent clients though.

Maximum throughput for a controlled number clients: use synchronous methods
Reaching maximum number of concurrent connections: async